# Clase JQUERY para controlar inputs

Tags: jquery

Mi pregunta posiblemente esté mal formulada, pero es que no he encontrado la manera de hacerla.
Tengo un campo input con bootstrap de esta manera:

```
<input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="form-control maxl-3n">
```

Decidí hacerlo de esta manera, porque no me convence tanto los parámetros HTML para  "maxlenght" y "range", pues no poseen el resultado que he esperado.

De este input, surge la clase "maxl-3n" que viene dentro de un .js, expresada de esta manera:

```
$('.maxl-3n').on('input', function () {
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
if (this.value.length > 3)
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, 3);
});
```

Lo que hace es controlar que el campo sea numérico (por eso la "n" al final) y que tenga una extensión máxima de 3 números enteros (del 0 al 999).

El problema? pues si tengo 100 inputs con diferentes tipos y diferentes extensiones máximas, debo crear cada clase por separado por cada uno de ellos.

Entonces... Es posible crear una única clase o función que controle cada uno de estos inputs sin necesidad de estar duplicando por cada tipo de input?

Por ejemplo, si establezco la clase como "maxl-5n" pues la función debe interpretar que aceptará un máximo de 5 caracteres numéricos enteros; si defino la clase como "maxl-5" solamente, aceptará un máximo de 5 caracteres alfanuméricos, y si se define por decir "maxl-5u" deberá convertir en mayúsculas cada carácter alfanumérico ingresado, y así, de acuerdo a la necesidad. Todo esto dentro de una misma clase o función para no tener que crear varias funciones por cada tipo de input.

Comment: Vas a tener multiples inputs solamente con esas condiciones o van a ver de otro tipo, porque sí todos los inputs que pongas van a ser así como ese, pues símplemente los señalas todos

Comment: Ahh, claro... No se me había ocurrido eso. Tenés razón.

Comment: Ahí puse un ejemplo para que lo pruebes

Answer (score 3):

creo que puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

Asigna un atributo adicional a tus elementos input

```
<input type="text" name="id" data-length="1" 
        class="form-control maxl">

<input type="text" name="id" data-length="8" 
        class="form-control maxl">
```

Esta es tu función modificada, para que tome el valor que hayas guardado en el atributo `data-length`:

```
$('.maxl').on('input', function () {
let Mlenght =  $(this).attr("data-length");

this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
if (this.value.length > +Mlenght)
this.value = this.value.slice(0, +Mlenght);
});
```

Ahora todos los input con la clase .maxl tendrán un maxLength dinámico. Como podrás imaginar mediante el uso de estos atributos podrás utilizar otras validaciones del tipo String, Number, etc. Si te preguntas porque utilizo la variable que guarda el valor del atributo de la siguiente manera `+Mlenght`es debido a que la `.attr()` devuelve una cadena. Al anteponer el signo `+` hago un conversión implícita de cadena a número para evitar posibles errores.

**Nota:** Si usas jQuery >= 1.4.3, debes obtener el atributo mediante la función `.data()`

Prueba y valida. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Sí todos los inputs que pongas quieres que se comporten igual simplemente seleccionas todos los inputs así `$("input").` por lo tanto quedaría algo así:

```js
$("input").on('input', function () {
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
if (this.value.length > 3)
    this.value = this.value.slice(0, 3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
```

Otra cosa que podrías hacer para no hacer muchas funciones y vas a tener inputs con diferentes comportamientos y los vas a diferencias con la clase, pues podrías hacer algo así:

```js
function maxlen(limit){
  $(".maxl-"+limit+"n").on('input', function () {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  if (this.value.length > limit)
      this.value = this.value.slice(0, limit);
  });
}
maxlen(3);
maxlen(5);
```

```css
.maxl-3n{
  color: blue
}

.maxl-5n{
  color: gray
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-5n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-5n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Creo que en la primera frase se te ha colado `$(input).` faltan las comillas `$("input").`. En el código lo tienes bien :)

Comment: @x3k_js Gracias, según yo lo habías editado tú porque no me había fijado, que raro, igual gracias

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es sí. Aunque si puedes crear clases concretas que se repitan en firentes inputs y luego ir concatenánolas en el class para que vaya asumiendo dichas características. Puedes crear regularExpression específicos e incluso no hace falta que hagas según que funciones si lo necesitas en que te valide los inputs en vivo con atributos como "maxlengh", "minlenght", "max", "min", required, type"email", type="number", etc... ya puedes controlar según necesidades.

te recomiendo revisar la siguiente documentación: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input

Answer (score 0):

Propongo otra solución para no crear un evento diferente por cada clase `maxl-*n` diferente:

Se basa en filtrar los elementos por los de la clase correspondiente

```
$("input").filter(function() {
    return this.className.match(/maxl\-\d+n/);
})...
```

Después como ya sabemos que contiene esa clase simplemente la buscamos con `.match` y nos quedamos con la primera (ojo con poner varias de estas clases juntas)

```
let clase=$(this).attr("class").match(/maxl\-\d+n/);
```

y del mismo modo nos quedamos con el `n` de esa clase:

```
let n=clase[0].match(/\d+/);
```

El resto como explica @DaxTter77 en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/313435/128699)

---

**NOTA:** Es posible que la regex se pueda mejorar (no soy un experto)

---

**Snippet:**

```js
$("input").filter(function() {
    return this.className.match(/maxl\-\d+n/);
  }).on('input', function () {
    let clase=$(this).attr("class").match(/maxl\-\d+n/);
    let n=clase[0].match(/\d+/);
    //Esta parte es de la respuesta de @DaxTter77
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
    if (this.value.length > n[0]){
        this.value = this.value.slice(0, n[0]);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-1n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-2n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-3n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-4n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-5n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-6n">
<input type="text" class="form-control maxl-12n">
```